# css cubic-bezier behaves differently in IE11 and Edge vs. Chrome

Tags: css, cubic-bezier

I have the following CSS rule:

```
div {
    width:10%; background:black;
    transition: width 2s cubic-bezier(.15,.88,0,.99);
    -o-transition: width 2s cubic-bezier(.15,.88,0,.99);
    -ms-transition: width 2s cubic-bezier(.15,.88,0,.99);
    -moz-transition: width 2s cubic-bezier(.15,.88,0,.99);
    -webkit-transition: width 2s cubic-bezier(.15,.88,0,.99);
}
div:hover {
    width:100%;
}
```

When I mouse over the div in both Chrome, IE and Edge, I will see the width animate from 10% to 100%.

When I mouse over the div in Chrome, the animation speed starts fast and ends slow.  When I mouse out, the animation speed starts fast and ends slow.

When I mouse over the div in IE 11 or Edge, the animation speed starts fast and ends slow.  When I mouse out, **the animation speed starts slow and ends fast.**

Can I get IE11 and Edge to behave the same as Chrome?  If so, how do I do it?